# Swift 3 SegmentedController how do I set a segment as 'selected'?

Tags: swift, segment, segmentedcontrol

This should be easy (it was in Objective-C) but I've not been able to find anything through search.

I want to set a segment such as `selected = true` or `selected = false!` I won't add any code but will just say the `segmentedController` is connected as an **IBOutlet**.

Comment: If it was *easy in Objective-C* it's easy in Swift, too. In the documentation you can switch between Swift and ObjC to figure out the syntax.

Comment: Really helpful. Not! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should give segment action and in segment action you write the code it will work fine

```
if segment.isselected{
  //try what you want
}
```

else{
    }

Comment: For anyone else looking for this:


              myFirstSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
              myFirstSegment.isSelected = true